# Button not clickable in IE, but works in modern browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

In the example here, `button.vertical-button__btn` with the text "Description" is hoverable and clickable in all browsers but IE. (I've put a CSS border on hover to illustrate this. You can also see when the button is clickable by the 'hand' pointer appearing.)

***A caveat:*** When I say it is not clickable in IE, I mean that the full button text (highlighted in yellow) is not clickable. Oddly, the extreme right edge of the `button` element does click and hover as intended.

What is causing this behavior, and how can I make the functionality the same in IE as with modern browsers?

I am only interested in supporting IE 11 and Edge... IE 10 and under do not need to be supported.

**Edit:**
Another odd behavior: If I remove the element `div.project__image` The button becomes clickable, but I cannot figure out why, and I need the div element to remain.

```css
.project {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 740px;
    height: 295px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.project__image, .project__text {
    position: relative;
    width: 280px;
    max-width: 408px;
    height: 210px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.project__text {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px 8px 20px 8px;
}

.vertical-button {
    width: 1px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    top: calc(50% - 10px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: 0.8s;
    -ms-transition: 0.8s;
    -o-transition: 0.8s;
    transition: 0.8s;
}
.vertical-button__btn, 
.vertical-button__btn:focus, 
.vertical-button__btn:active {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    display: inline;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    outline-offset: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    transform-origin: left top;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-32%);
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
.vertical-button__btn:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.vertical-button__stroke {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="project project--active">
    <div class="project__image">
        <a href="http://www.soupisgoodfood.com">
            <img class="image" alt="soupisgoodfood.com" src="img/hl.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="project__text">
        <h3 class="project__heading">Soup Overflow</h3>
        <p class="project__tagline">Soup Overflow, the creative agency of Vegetables</p>
        <ul>
            <li class="project__list-item">
                <a class="project__link" href="http://www.soupisgoodfood.com">View Flavors</a>
            </li>
            <li class="project__list-item project__button">
                <a class="project__link" href="">Description</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="vertical-button">
            <button class="vertical-button__btn" style="background-color: yellow;">Description</button>
            <div class="vertical-button__stroke"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked your snippet with IE11 ? It works fine with my IE11 in W7. On my side, no issues to notice :) even on IE10 emulated

Comment: That's odd... Even now when I try it (including the snippet) it doesn't work. On Windows 7 with IE 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that it's a matter of z-index.
If you add a `z-index: 200` to your `vertical-button`, the button will be clickable, even in IE.

```css
.project {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 740px;
    height: 295px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.project__image, .project__text {
    position: relative;
    width: 280px;
    max-width: 408px;
    height: 210px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.project__text {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px 8px 20px 8px;
}

.vertical-button {
    width: 1px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    top: calc(50% - 10px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: 0.8s;
    -ms-transition: 0.8s;
    -o-transition: 0.8s;
    transition: 0.8s;
z-index: 200
}
.vertical-button__btn, 
.vertical-button__btn:focus, 
.vertical-button__btn:active {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    display: inline;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    outline-offset: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    transform-origin: left top;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-32%);
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
.vertical-button__btn:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.vertical-button__stroke {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="project project--active">
    <div class="project__image">
        <a href="http://www.soupisgoodfood.com">
            <img class="image" alt="soupisgoodfood.com" src="img/hl.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="project__text">
        <h3 class="project__heading">Soup Overflow</h3>
        <p class="project__tagline">Soup Overflow, the creative agency of Vegetables</p>
        <ul>
            <li class="project__list-item">
                <a class="project__link" href="http://www.soupisgoodfood.com">View Flavors</a>
            </li>
            <li class="project__list-item project__button">
                <a class="project__link" href="">Description</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="vertical-button">
            <button class="vertical-button__btn" style="background-color: yellow;">Description</button>
            <div class="vertical-button__stroke"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! That did it!